# How to check requests from a service worker in firefox?

Tags: firefox-developer-tools

I have a registered service worker which initiates web requests via `cache.add()` function.
But I can not find those requests in the **Network** panel of the dev tools in firefox.
How can I check those requests?

**===Edit on 2023-06-25===**

I found 2 related issues here on bugzilla: [1432311](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1432311) and [1267119](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1267119). Expecting these bugs will be fixed soon.